# Load dataset from Roboflow in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo, yolov5, roboflow

I'm trying to retreive a roboflow project dataset in google colab. It works for two of the dataset versions, but not the latest I have created (same project, version 5).

Anyone know what goes wrong?

Snippet:

```
from roboflow import Roboflow
rf = Roboflow(api_key="keyremoved") 
project = rf.workspace().project("project name")
dataset = project.version(5).download("yolov5")

loading Roboflow workspace...
loading Roboflow project...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-7f073ab2bc86> in <module>()
      7 rf = Roboflow(api_key="keyremoved")
      8 project = rf.workspace().project("projectname")
----> 9 dataset = project.version(5).download("yolov5")
     10 
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/roboflow/core/version.py in download(self, model_format, location)
     76                 link = resp.json()['export']['link']
     77             else:
---> 78                 raise RuntimeError(resp.json())
     79 
     80         def bar_progress(current, total, width=80):

RuntimeError: {'error': {'message': 'Unsupported get request. Export with ID `idremoved` does not exist or cannot be loaded due to missing permissions.', 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'hint': 'You can find the API docs at https://docs.roboflow.com'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be limits for the number of images+augmentations that you can export with roboflow  according to the plans that you use. Please check your account details and limits. Contact roboflow support if you need more help.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think so. Strangely enough, it started working about and hour after this post. No changes. I suspect there is some kind of strange delay from publishing datasets to beeing able to download them. I will investigate further.